UML owner(s) of ParameterSet
Under the description of ParameterSet in section 9.9.16 on p. 190, the diagrams mentioned (Features and Behaviors) show that ParameterSet can be owned either by a BehavioralFeature or by a Behavior. However, the constraints under section 9.9.16.5 seem to assume that it will be owned by BehavioralFeature?
For example:
• input
If a parameterized entity has input Parameters that are in a ParameterSet, then any inputs that are not in a
ParameterSet must be streaming. Same for output Parameters.

inv: ((parameter->exists(direction = ParameterDirectionKind::_'in')) implies
behavioralFeature.ownedParameter->select(p | p.direction = ParameterDirectionKind::_'in'
and p.parameterSet->isEmpty())->forAll(isStream))
and
((parameter->exists(direction = ParameterDirectionKind::out)) implies
behavioralFeature.ownedParameter->select(p | p.direction = ParameterDirectionKind::out
and p.parameterSet->isEmpty())->forAll(isStream))

Also, this particular constraint ignores the inout and return parameters. I couldn't find any reference that would prohibit such parameters from being elements of a ParameterSet, although it is not clear to me how they would be used.
================
EDIT:
If I understand Axel's comment correctly, then the owner of ParameterSet can still be either Behavior or BehavioralFeature, but the constraint would have to accomodate both. Here is my attempt at an OCL implementation:
inv: if behavioralFeature <> null then
       ((parameter->exists(direction = ParameterDirectionKind::_'in')) implies
       behavioralFeature.ownedParameter->select(p | p.direction = ParameterDirectionKind::_'in'
       and p.parameterSet->isEmpty())->forAll(isStream))
       and
       ((parameter->exists(direction = ParameterDirectionKind::out)) implies
       behavioralFeature.ownedParameter->select(p | p.direction = ParameterDirectionKind::out
       and p.parameterSet->isEmpty())->forAll(isStream))
     else
       ((parameter->exists(direction = ParameterDirectionKind::_'in')) implies
       behavior.ownedParameter->select(p | p.direction = ParameterDirectionKind::_'in'
       and p.parameterSet->isEmpty())->forAll(isStream))
       and
       ((parameter->exists(direction = ParameterDirectionKind::out)) implies
       behavior.ownedParameter->select(p | p.direction = ParameterDirectionKind::out
       and p.parameterSet->isEmpty())->forAll(isStream))
     endif

Would this be consistent with the UML intent?
As to the inout and return parameters, I suppose they just do not belong in a ParameterSet. Ideally, there should be an additional constraint restricting the allowed parameter direction.

You are absolutely right. I guess this has been overlooked by https://issues.omg.org/browse/UML24-119 where the two definitions of parameters in UML 2.4 have been merged into one.

@Axel Thank you! Does this mean that Behavior is no longer allowed as owner if the merged definition is respected? And should I file an issue on the OMG site? Behavior would also no longer have the asasociation ownedParameterSet, I assume.

Both should be possible owners with exactly the same associations and constraints. I would need to look up the old version, but I'm pretty sure, that this was the original intent. Filing an issue is a good idea (even though work on UML is not really progressing right now, to say the least). So, don't expect a solution in the near future.

@AxelScheithauer guess you should make that an answer.

In the UML 2.4.1 it looked like this:

All the constraints didn't have a formal specification with OCL, but from the description and the diagram we see, that the intention was to treat both cases the same. I guess it was just forgotten to implement the case of behaviors. Also the input and output parameters are described informally. So, I think any input is meant by this, and this includes inout parameters and any output is meant including inout and return parameters.
So, your OCL needs to become even more complicated. You could save some space by declaring a variable ownedParameter.

Thank you -- this is very helpful! I shall use this information to put together an issue on the OMG site.
